# Can I currently develop, test, package and distribute Kivy, cross-platform apps on Windows 10 alone?

Tags: cross-platform, kivy, development-environment

Can I currently, at this time, develop, test, package and distribute Kivy, cross-platform apps (targeted to run on iOS, Android, Windows, OS X and Linux) on Windows 10 alone?

I.E. WITHOUT needing a Linux or OS X machine?

I ask because Buildozer used to need to run on linux or OS X. Maybe it has improved or there's something better now?

If not, what will aspects of the process can be done on Windows 10 and to what other machines do i need access?

Thanks for the help.

Love and peace,

Joe

Comment: Funny thing is, that no matter how far is Kivy with android development, the most useful would probably be to use OS X machine if you want to use, well.. one physical machine - VM for win, lin, android; Xcode for Mac/iOS. Not sure about drivers in VMs, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can run buildozer in a virtual machine running linux, but in won't run under windows alone at the moment (or, it will, but not the android build part, which is what you need).